# scanbd doesn't work unless I restart it from the command line

Tags: debian, scanning, init.d, sane

NAME "Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID "7"
VERSION "7 (wheezy)”

Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux

I’ve installed SANE and scanbd with a Canoscan LIDA 210. [From Instructions Here](http://thehomeserverhandbook.com/2012/03/18/scanbd_part2/) I’ve put in an /etc/init.d script copied from the example script that came with scanbd. The only modifications are to the paths, and I added ‘$ALL’ to the Required-Start:’.

THE ISSUE IS: The scanner buttons won’t work until I re-start the scanbd process manually from the command line, as root, using ‘service scanbd restart’. Then all is good. The service still appears to be running as saned.

But this is a project that will not have a head…so this will not work in the long run. I have been working under the assumption that the startup may simply be occurring too soon in the boot process, but this may not be the issue.

Please see code below.

=== After reboot, BEFORE service restart ===

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ps -ef  | grep -i scan
saned     3119     1  0 09:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/scanbd -c /usr/local/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
root      3242  3239  0 09:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i scan
```

=== service scanbd restart ===

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/init.d# service scanbd restart
[ ok ] Restarting SANE scanner button daemon: scanbd.
root@raspberrypi:/etc/init.d#
```

=== (AFTER service restart) ===

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/init.d# ps -ef | grep -i scan
saned     3352     1  0 09:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/scanbd -c /usr/local/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
root      3371  3243  0 09:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i scan
```

=== /etc/init.d/scanbd ===

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# $Id: scanbd.debian 203 2015-02-04 08:05:20Z wimalopaan $
#
#  scanbd - KMUX scanner button daemon
#
#  Copyright (C) 2008 - 2015  Wilhelm Meier (wilhelm.meier@fh-kl.de)
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ...Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named networking bootlogs saned cups dbus
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scanbd
# Required-Start:    $ALL 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Scanner button events daemon
# Description:       scanbd associates actions to scanner buttons
### END INIT INFO

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="SANE scanner button daemon"
NAME=scanbd
DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-c /usr/local/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started

        export SANE_CONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/etc/scanbd
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
    #
    # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
    # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
    #
    #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    #do_reload
    #log_end_msg $?
    #;;
  restart|force-reload)
    #
    # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
    # 'force-reload' alias
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

=== insserv -s ===

```
K:01:0 1 6:fail2ban
K:09:0 6:umountfs
K:05:0 6:umountnfs.sh
K:03:0 6:sendsigs
K:07:0 6 S:hwclock.sh
K:07:0 6:networking
K:04:0 1 6:rsyslog
K:01:0 1 6:ifplugd
K:10:0 6:umountroot
K:01:0 1 6:fake-hwclock
K:01:0 1 6:scanbd
K:01:0 6:plymouth
K:11:0:halt
K:01:0 1 6:saned
K:02:0 1 6:avahi-daemon
K:06:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S:nfs-common
K:06:0 1 6:rpcbind
K:01:0 1 6:cgroup-bin
K:01:0 6:urandom
K:08:0 1 6:iptables-persistent
K:01:0 1 6:lightdm
K:01:0 1 6:exim4
K:11:6:reboot
K:01:0 1 6:triggerhappy
K:01:0 1 6:xinetd
K:01:0 1 6:alsa-utils
K:01:0 1 6:nfs-kernel-server
K:01:1:cups
S:02:S:udev
S:03:S:keyboard-setup
S:16:S:console-setup
S:02:2 3 4 5:fail2ban
S:08:S:mountall.sh
S:09:S:mountall-bootclean.sh
S:13:S:mountnfs.sh
S:14:S:mountnfs-bootclean.sh
S:11:S:networking
S:01:2 3 4 5:rsyslog
S:01:2 3 4 5:ifplugd
S:01:S:fake-hwclock
S:05:S:checkroot.sh
S:14:2 3 4 5:scanbd
S:14:2 3 4 5:plymouth
S:04:2 3 4 5:saned
S:02:2 3 4 5:dbus
S:03:2 3 4 5:avahi-daemon
S:12:2 3 4 5 S:rpcbind
S:01:2 3 4 5:cgroup-bin
S:01:S:mountkernfs.sh
S:10:S:urandom
S:01:2 3 4 5:iptables-persistent
S:03:2 3 4 5:lightdm
S:17:S:x11-common
S:15:S:kbd
S:02:2 3 4 5:exim4
S:04:S:mountdevsubfs.sh
S:01:2 3 4 5:triggerhappy
S:02:2 3 4 5:xinetd
S:17:S:alsa-utils
S:13:2 3 4 5:nfs-kernel-server
S:01:1:killprocs
S:04:2 3 4 5:cups
S:01:1 2 3 4 5:motd
S:01:S:hostname.sh
S:01:1 2 3 4 5:bootlogs
S:02:1:single
S:02:2 3 4 5:ntp
S:02:2 3 4 5:dphys-swapfile
S:02:2 3 4 5:cron
S:14:2 3 4 5:rmnologin
S:01:2 3 4 5:sudo
S:14:2 3 4 5:rc.local
S:02:2 3 4 5:ssh
S:02:2 3 4 5:rsync
S:07:S:checkfs.sh
S:06:S:mtab.sh
S:17:S:bootmisc.sh
S:06:S:kmod
S:06:S:checkroot-bootclean.sh
S:17:S:plymouth-log
S:17:S:raspi-config
S:10:S:procps
S:10:S:udev-mtab
```

=== /etc/xinetd.d/sane-port ===

```
service sane-port
{
        port        = 6566
        socket_type = stream
        wait        = no
        user        = saned
        group       = scanner
        server      = /usr/local/sbin/scanbm
        server_args = scanbm -c /usr/local/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
        disable     = no
}
```

=== /etc/default/saned ===

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

# Set to yes to start saned
RUN=no

# Set to the user saned should run as
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

=== /etc/sane.d/dll.conf ===

```
## /etc/sane.d/dll.conf - Configuration file for the SANE dynamic backend loader
##
## Backends can also be enabled by configuration snippets under
## /etc/sane.d/dll.d directory -- packages providing backends should drop
## a config file similar to dll.conf in this directory, named after the package.
##
#
## The next line enables the network backend; comment it out if you don't need
## to use a remote SANE scanner over the network - see sane-net(5) and saned(8)
net
```

=== /etc/sane.d/net.conf ===

```
# This is the net backend config file.

## net backend options
# Timeout for the initial connection to saned. This will prevent the backend
# from blocking for several minutes trying to connect to an unresponsive
# saned host (network outage, host down, ...). Value in seconds.
# connect_timeout = 60

## saned hosts
# Each line names a host to attach to.
# If you list "localhost" then your backends can be accessed either
# directly or through the net backend.  Going through the net backend
# may be necessary to access devices that need special privileges.
# localhost
connect_timeout = 3
localhost # scanbm is listening on localhost
```

=== /usr/local/etc/scanbd/dll.conf ===

```
# /etc/sane.d/dll.conf - Configuration file for the SANE dynamic backend loader
#
# Backends can also be enabled by configuration snippets under
# /etc/sane.d/dll.d directory -- packages providing backends should drop
# a config file similar to dll.conf in this directory, named after the package.
#

# The next line enables the network backend; comment it out if you don't need
# to use a remote SANE scanner over the network - see sane-net(5) and saned(8)
#net
abaton
agfafocus
apple
avision
artec
artec_eplus48u
as6e
bh
canon
canon630u
canon_dr
#canon_pp
cardscan
coolscan
#coolscan2
coolscan3
#dc25
#dc210
#dc240
dell1600n_net
dmc
epjitsu
#epson
epson2
fujitsu
#gphoto2
genesys
gt68xx
hp
hp3900
hpsj5s
hp3500
hp4200
hp5400
hp5590
hpljm1005
hs2p
ibm
kodak
kvs1025
kvs20xx
leo
lexmark
ma1509
magicolor
matsushita
microtek
microtek2
mustek
#mustek_pp
mustek_usb
mustek_usb2
nec
niash
#p5
pie
pixma
plustek
#plustek_pp
#pnm
qcam
ricoh
rts8891
s9036
sceptre
sharp
sm3600
sm3840
snapscan
sp15c
#st400
#stv680
tamarack
teco1
teco2
teco3
#test
u12
umax
#umax_pp
umax1220u
v4l
xerox_mfp
```

=== /usr/local/etc/scanbd/saned.conf ===

```
# saned.conf
# Configuration for the saned daemon

## Daemon options
# Port range for the data connection. Choose a range inside [1024 - 65535].
# Avoid specifying too large a range, for performance reasons.
#
# ONLY use this if your saned server is sitting behind a firewall. If your
# firewall is a Linux machine, we strongly recommend using the
# Netfilter nf_conntrack_sane connection tracking module instead.
#
# data_portrange = 10000 - 10100


## Access list
# A list of host names, IP addresses or IP subnets (CIDR notation) that
# are permitted to use local SANE devices. IPv6 addresses must be enclosed
# in brackets, and should always be specified in their compressed form.
#
# The hostname matching is not case-sensitive.

#scan-client.somedomain.firm
#192.168.0.1
#192.168.0.1/29
#[2001:7a8:185e::42:12]
#[2001:7a8:185e::42:12]/64

# NOTE: /etc/inetd.conf (or /etc/xinetd.conf) and
# /etc/services must also be properly configured to start
# the saned daemon as documented in saned(8), services(4)
# and inetd.conf(4) (or xinetd.conf(5)).
192.168.178.0/24
```

Comment: File a bug report with Ubuntu or Debian so I can have a look at it